# How can I change project view on eclipse to hierarchical only using Linux terminal command?

Tags: linux, eclipse, shell, ubuntu, terminal

How can I change project view on eclipse from flat to hierarchical only using Linux terminal command without right click on the menu?

Comment: You can't, there is no Eclipse command line option that would do this.

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no command line option for this, it is possible to switch the presention between flat and hierarchical using only the keyboard, if you are already in the Project Explorer view.

Press Ctrl+F10 to display the view menu. Use the arrow keys to highlight the menu item you want (in this case, the Presentation menu item is the first, so just one press on the down arrow), then use the right arrow to show the sub-menu for that item. From there, you can either use the hot key (underlined in the submenu, so "f" for "Flat, "h" for "Hierarchical) or use the up and down arrow keys, then hit Enter when on the item you want.